Can't remove gradlew in react-native
I can't run my react-native project and this is the error I get.
After searching, I decided to remove gradlew and I still have the same error.
Thank you in advance for any assistance or help.
I tried to delete node-modules and installed again but it is still the same.

Before asking question, it may be beneficial to take the tour and read the various pages in the help center, particularly How to Ask or Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?.
